# Refresh the table view on collection.fetch() method

Tags: jquery, backbone.js, backbone-views

Consider following Scenario:-

**- Model of a Player**

```
 var Player = Backbone.Model.extend({
         defaults: {
PlayerId: 0,
PlayerName: "",
IsActive: false
}
    });
```

**Collection Model is as follows:**

```
 var PlayerList = Backbone.Collection.extend({
            model: Player,
            url: '/Match/GetPlayers/'
        });
```

**List View is as follows:**

```
 var ListView = Backbone.View.extend({
        el: '#ListContainer',
        initialize: function () {
            _.bindAll(this, 'render');
            this.collection.on('reset', this.render);


        },
        render: function () {
            if (this.collection.length > 0) {
            this.collection.each(this.AppendPlayer, this);
            }
            return this;
        },
        AppendPlayer: function (data) {
            var palyerView= new PlayerView({ model: data });
            $(this.el).find('table').append(genreView.render().el);

        },
        events: {
            "click #btnplay": "CheckStatus"
        },

        CheckStatus: function () {

            // alert();
           //here i will make a ajax call and get update the status of player
             which comes from other REST service.
        }


    });
```

**Below is the PlayerView:**

```
var PlayerView = Backbone.View.extend({
        tagName: "tr",            
        template: _.template($("#player-Template").html()),
        render: function () {

            this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));

        return this;
    }
    });
```

**HTML is as follows:**

```
<div id="ListContainer">
    <input type="button" id="btnplay" value="StatusCheck" />
    <table id="myTable">
        <tr>
            <td>Player Id</td>
            <td>Name</td>
            <td>Statu</td>
        </tr>

    </table>
</div>
<br />
<br />

<script id='player-Template' type='text/template'>
    <td><%=PlayerId%></td>
    <td><%=PlayerName%></td>    
    <td><%=IsActive%></td> 
</script>
```

so when i click the "Play" button it calls my API service and gets me an updated collection.

and i try to refresh the collection and the view using below logic:

```
PlayerList.fetch({
                    success: function (collection, resp) {
                        //console.log('success' + resp); //

                    },
                    error: function (er) {
                        console.log('error: %o', er)
                    },
                    reset: true,

                });
```

I get the updated model back but what happen is the updated model get's appended with the existing rows.

I need to clear the existing rows and repopulate it with my new collection.

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`empty()`](https://api.jquery.com/empty/) the table inside the render method:

```
render: function () {
  this.$el.find('table').empty(); // clears existing rows 
  if (this.collection.length > 0) {
     this.collection.each(this.AppendPlayer, this);
  }
  return this;
}
```

---

BTW, you don't have to do `$(this.el)`, backbone provides a jQuery instance of your view's element via `this.$el`.

Unless you're reusing the `AppendPlayer` (I suggest using camelCase for method names. Use pascal case only for constructor functions) method, you can simply do the following:

```
render: function() {
  var $table = this.$el.find('table');
  $table.empty();
  if (this.collection.length) {
    this.collection.each(function(model) {
      $table.append(new PlayerView({
        model: model
      }).render().el);
    });
  }
  return this;
}
```

and if you modify the playerView to render itself as shown below:

```
var PlayerView = Backbone.View.extend({
  tagName: "tr",
  template: _.template($("#player-Template").html()),
  initialize: function() {
    this.render();
  },
  render: function() {
    this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
    return this;
  }
});
```

You can just do:

```
render: function() {
  var $table = this.$el.find('table');
  $table.empty();
  if (this.collection.length) {
    this.collection.each(function(model) {
      $table.append(new PlayerView({
        model: model
      }).el);
    });
  }
  return this;
}
```

---

Side note: you seems to be creating `palyerView` but you're appending `genreView` ..?!

Comment: ok a quick thing. $table.empty() also cleared the table heading? How can i avoid/ re-create them

Comment: @Darshan assuming your headers are inside `<thead>`, empty the `<tbody>` : `var $table = this.$el.find('table tbody');`